# Why is it easy for the Gibbs sampler to take long time to converge to target distribution?

Tags: bayesian, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

This is related to Gelman's *[Bayesian Data Analysis](https://amzn.to/3HfBoPz)* 3rd Edition pg 300 first paragraph of Section 12.4. The book says the following.

> "An inherent inefficiency in the Gibbs sampler and Metropolis
> algorithm is their random walk behavior ... can take a long time
> zigging and zagging while moving through the target distribution."

For the Metropolis algorithm, the reason for taking a long time to zigging and zagging to converge is not surprising due to jumping distribution choice with narrow "width". This will produce local random walk behavior.

I cannot see why the Gibbs sampler has this inherent problem. Suppose I have $p(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n|y)$ posterior. Denote $\theta_{-i}$ as all $\theta$'s other than $\theta_i$. Denote $\theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n)$.

The Gibbs sampler basically iteratively picks $\theta_1$ from $p(\theta_1|\theta_{-1},y)$, $\theta_2$ from $p(\theta_2|\theta_{-2},y)$,... Each step changes only one component of $\theta$.

**Question:** What property of the Gibbs sampler drives inefficiency? For Gaussian $p(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_n|y)$ case, it is clear as given in [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions%27s) covariance and mean of conditional, by noting attenuation of covariance of conditionals. Then inefficiency is apparent. However, I do not find that argument is applicable in full generality as Metropolis algorithm's inefficiency by bad choice of jumping distribution.

Comment: Hint: consider what happens when the parameters are correlated. For simplicity suppose you have two parameters. Draw a few iterations of the Gibbs sampler. I don't have time to find a passage, but I'm sure this is well-discussed in BDA

Comment: @Taylor Yes. I think it is clear to me on Gaussian case for now. The correlation basically attenuates the width of jumping in Gibbs sampler. That drives inefficiency. But this is a model dependent statement as compared to Metropolis algorithm's inefficiency being built in by choice of jumping distribution. Is the statement(Gibbs sampler is inefficient) true under some general conditions such as non zero correlation and etc?

Comment: Yes it's posterior/model dependent. Multimodal, correlated, high-dimensional posteriors, etc. can always be a problem. Gibbs doesn't always work poorly, though. To be any more specific, you'd have to define inefficient

Comment: @Taylor By inefficient, I mean convergence of distribution takes very long time. It seems that you are trying to assert a more general statement that correlation forces attenuation in the width of conditional distribution of Gibbs sampler. I might be wrong on that. I would expect convergence should be somehow related to $Var(\theta_i|\theta_{-i},y)$ with larger maybe better. Multimodal issue is relatively easy to see in both cases. High dimensionality problem is not entirely clear from the algorithms, but I guess it is the trouble of sampling grows exponentially.

Comment: If you want some theoretical results you might google something like “(bounds on the) mixing time” and “Gibbs”. Or are you looking for anecdotes/examples/plots? When I read your original quoted passage I’m getting the sense it’s more of a segue into a plug for score-based methods and in particular their HMC algo

Comment: @Taylor Thanks for the hint on googling keyword. I think that would clarify on various of convergence issues which I had in my mind.